# Prevent Salesforce for Outlook add-ins from being disabled

Tags: email

How to not have Salesforce for Outlook add-ins disabled when Outlook does not respond? Outlook 2010/Windows7.

Comment: Neal do you mean the plugins are disabled following a crash?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent this behavior. This is a feature of Microsoft Office to attempt to restore functionality after the program hangs. The new version should be less susceptible to crashes since it is now an external program that uses an API to communicate with Outlook indirectly.